# Prove: $A=A^\prime$ and $B=B^\prime$ does not imply $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

The only given condition is that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices of same order. I want to prove that this doesn't imply that $AB = BA$.

I tried proving this by contradiction.
All I got is
$$AB = BA = (A^\prime B^\prime)^\prime = (B^\prime A^\prime)^\prime$$
I don't know how to proceed after this, I don't know any contradicting facts to this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give a counterexample.

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 2 \\ 2 && 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

It follows that $AB = \begin{pmatrix}1 && 2 \\ 0 && 0  \end{pmatrix} \not= \begin{pmatrix}1 && 0 \\ 2 && 0 \end{pmatrix} = BA$.

Comment: is it only way we could prove it? cant we prove by some general arguments?

Comment: No, because there are some examples where the statement holds. For example, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 && 2 \\2 && 0 \end{pmatrix}$. It follows that $AB = BA$. 

Another examples: $A = \begin{pmatrix} a && b \\b && c \end{pmatrix}= B$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. It follows that $AB = A^{2} = BA$.